# UIButton of type UIButtonTypeCustom will not display Title (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I must have overlooked something completely obvious?? but my button displays its image and size correctly, but I simply can't get the Title to show up.

I did a really simple test, the Title does not even show up when I do this:

```
    CGRect frameBtn = CGRectMake(160.0f, 150.0f, 144.0f, 42.0f);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_halfscreen_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:frameBtn];
    NSLog(@"Title:%@", [button currentTitle]);
    //prints "Title:Hello
    [self addSubview:button];
```

I have a factory class that generates custom buttons for me and I thought I messed some detail up there, so I moved the above code directly into my `UIView`, the title is still blank.

Is this a bug or am I simply missing something right in front of my eyes.

Thank you for the extra set of eyes:)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Image overrides title, you need to make the image a background image to show the title.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_halfscreen_button.png"] 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you Tuomas:)
I was pulling my hair out on this one!
I thought something like that was going on so I even tried stuff like
"bringSubViewToFront" in desperation.
I missed the background part in the documentation.
Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks to Tuomas!  I was very puzzled by this and this was the only answer I found.

Answer (score 29):

I just hab spome quite similar problem... Just set the title color, I guess the current one is white ;)

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Sometimes you even have to use setTitleColor rather than uibutton.titleLabel.textColor

Answer (score 13):

I found the problem!

It's not Image overriding the title.  It is being push off frame by the image.

Try use this:

`[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -img.size.width, 0.0, 0.0 )];`

Hope it helps!

Comment: This kind of worked for me.  I ended up using [btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0 )];  Yours pushed the text off to the left of the button.

Comment: Hi @arsenius UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) works for you may be because you have a wider frame width for the button. JapCon's -img.size.width may be because he has a different frame width for the button.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `UIButton`, button uses some built-in size for its frame.

You should set the frame:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

or even better and comfortable:

```
[button sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that the title was not shown. I forgot to set the frame property:

```
//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);
```