# Why Text Does Not Show Up for UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_on"] resizableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_off"] resizableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7,7,7)];

for (UIButton * button in @[self.catalog,self.business]) {
    [button setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
self.business.selected=true;
[self.business setTitle:@"Business" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.catalog setTitle:@"Catalog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The result is the text only show up when I press and hold the button. Not by default.

What's wrong?

Comment: Does `[[self.business titleLabel] setText:@"Business"];` work?

Comment: did you create button programmatically?

Comment: This might help you solve the issue:-

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2507262/1595039

Comment: As you can see I used setBackgroundImage and not setImage. The answer to the question suggest that the issue is setBackgroundImage. Button is an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 2):

set title for all states:

```
[self.business setTitle:@"Business" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.catalog setTitle:@"Catalog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.business setTitle:@"Business" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.catalog setTitle:@"Catalog" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.business setTitle:@"Business" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[self.catalog setTitle:@"Catalog" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Work?

Comment: I saw the UIButton on many states. None shows title. Why it's so difficult just to draw some button.

Comment: hey @JimThio: just do comment those two lines which have  setBackgroundImage. Add the above lines as well .Try this first. let me know if it works..

Comment: @Neelz why you set title for all states?  He is already setting title for normal state ! and in the selected state he needs an image!

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a bug.

Changing the text color to another color solve the problem. But I want white color. So what I did is there are 2 white box in the color.

The "default" white and the "white" white.

Change things to white white and voila it works.