# Text not visible in circular UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am adding a circular UIButton like this:

```
-(void)addInfoButton
{
    UIButton *pButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [pButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(infoButtonDidTap:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    pButton.frame = [self getInfoButtonFrame];

    pButton.clipsToBounds = NO;

    //half of the width
    pButton.layer.cornerRadius = BUTTON_HEIGHT/2.0f;
    pButton.layer.borderColor = self.tintColor.CGColor;
    pButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    pButton.titleLabel.text = @"F";

    pButton.titleLabel.textColor = self.tintColor;
    pButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    self.filterInfoButton = pButton;

    [self addSubview:pButton];
}
```

The text "F" is not visible when the button gets displayed. What could be the reason?

Edit:
On setting the corner radius as 0, the text is visible. But then, the button is not circular.

Comment: can u see the button ?what is the button frame ?

Comment: Yes I can see the button completely.. the height and width of the button is 44 each

Comment: "What could be the reason?" All sorts of things – what is the tint colour you're trying to use for the text colour, for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton of type UIButtonTypeCustom will not display Title (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507248/uibutton-of-type-uibuttontypecustom-will-not-display-title-iphone)

Comment: the tint color for the text is the same as that of the border color of the button.. which is actually the basic tint color of the view.. let me set some other color and verify..

Comment: @Mr.T I am not setting any image to my button..

Answer (score 1):

You set the title of a UIButton using

```
- setTitle:forState:
```

> Sets the title to use for the specified state.

Using the attribute titleLabel does not set the text it is used to customize the button's title label.

```
titleLabel
```

> A view that displays the value of the currentTitle property for a button. (read-only) Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of the button. For example:

```
button.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
```